# Why while (*s++ != '\0') doesn't work?

Tags: c

I wrote a function copies the string t to the end of s, it works if I write like this

```
    char strcat(char *s, char *t) {
    while (*s != '\0')
        s++;
    while ((*s++ = *t++) != '\0')
        ;
    }
```

However, it doesn't work if I write it like this

```
    char strcat(char *s, char *t) {
    while (*s++ != '\0')
        ;
    while ((*s++ = *t++) != '\0')
        ;
    }
```

I don't understand what's the difference between

```
while (*s++ != '\0')
        ;
```

and

```
while (*s != '\0')
        s++;
```

Comment: Hint: What happens to `s` if the very first element is `'\0'` in the two loops in question? Process the loops by hand (or pen and paper).

Comment: The code is also wrong in that it should return the destination string (as a char *).

Comment: It do not need to return a value, as the purpose of this function is change the value of char s[] through pointer, and it works as long as you give enough space in s to hold the combination.

Comment: @Chen If you're implementing the equivalent of the standard library function strcat, then it should return the destination string. If you're not implementing that, then your function is still problematic because it's defined to return char but it returns nothing. It should probably be void instead.

Comment: @jarmod Yep you are right, it should be void. thanks for let me know that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you use

```
while (*s++ != '\0');
```

`s` points to one character past the null character when the loop breaks. You end up copying the contents of `t` to `s` but after the null character.

If `s` is `"string 1"` before the function and `t` is `"string 2"`, at the end of the function, you will end up with a character array that will look like:

```
{'s', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g', ' ', '1', '\0', 's', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g', ' ', '2', '\0', ... }
                                         ^^^^
```

Due to the existence of the null character in the middle, you won't see `"string 2"` in most uses.

On the other hand, when you use:

```
while (*s != '\0')
        s++;
```

`s` points to the null character when the loop breaks. Given the same input, you will end up with a character array that will look like:

```
{'s', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g', ' ', '1', 's', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g', ' ', '2', '\0', ... }
                     No null character in the middle.
```

Comment: Whats the purpose of "\0" inside the `while`? How `while(*s++ != 0)` would be different?

Comment: @HugoNakamura, it's only a convention to make it clearer that you are comparing a character. `*s++ != 0` is exactly the same as `*s++ != '\0'`.